# Pass an integer to an Arduino

Tags: c#, serial-port, arduino

I am having some trouble passing over integers to the Arduino that is not a 1 or a 0. In this example I want to be able to pass a 3. The reason is that I will soon have more buttons controlling different parts of the Arduino and will need different integer values to do this.

Here is Arduino code..

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // Define the led pin as output
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}
void loop()
{
  // Read data from serial communication
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
  int b = Serial.read();
  // Note, I made it so that it's more sensitive to 0-40% load.
  // Since thats where it's usually at when using the computer as normal.

if (b == 3)
{
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
}
else if (b == 0)
{
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
}

Serial.flush();
}
}
```

Here is my C# code.

```
    int MyInt = 3;
    byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes(MyInt);


    private void OnButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        serialPort1.Write(b, 0, 4);
    }
    private void OffButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        serialPort1.Write(new byte[] { Convert.ToByte("0") }, 0, 1);
    }
```

I have two different ways of sending data through the serialport, but they both work in the same way. My question is how do I know what values are coming out of the Serial.read() at the Arduino side. When I choose any value that is not a 1 or a 0 in my C# program to send, such as a 3, the program does not work. Clearly 3 is not being sent over as 3 to the Arduino to be stored into an integer value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code slightly - int b is pulled out as a declaration at the top, 
and I changed your line b = Serial.read(); to b = Serial.read() - '0';

```
int b;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // Define the led pin as output
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}
void loop()
{
// Read data from serial communication
if (Serial.available() > 0) {

b = Serial.read() - '0';
// Note, I made it so that it's more sensitive to 0-40% load.
// Since thats where it's usually at when using the computer as normal.

if (b == 3)
{
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
}
else if (b == 0)
{
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
}

Serial.flush();
```

}
}

Comment: Also, I suppose you have two questions here - how do you get it working (see above) and how do you know what values are being collected by serial.read()? Serial.read() reads the ascii value, not the numeric equivalent, so you're reading '51' instead of 3. To get the number, subtract the ascii value of '0' (in single quotes). It's kinda confusing when you use the serial monitor because it does the ascii conversion for you, so you think you're just received a 3 when you've actually received '51'.

Comment: Perfect! I went ahead an started using the tables from http://ascii.cl/. I sent the the value of "ETX" as my integer value from the c# program and it came out as 3. The program worked. Great! A little weird that I can send ETX as an integer though. It goes against what I know about int, string, floats, etc.